# Inherited winforms controls not compiling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have the latest stable version of VS2019 with the latest version of Resharper installed.  When I create a control that inherits from Textbox I have 2 issues.

1) It does not show up in the toolbox after I build the solution, yes I have checked that the option to auto add to toolbox is enabled.

2) The new Textbox control, lets call it SpecialTextBox, is not being recognized as a control.  When I manually try to add SpecialTextBox to the forms Controls list, the compiler says it cannot convert from SpecialTextBox to System.Windows.Forms.Control.  But SpecialTextbox inherits from TextBox, which inherits from TextboxBase, which inherits from Control.

Here is the Code:

```
public class SpecialTextbox : TextBox, ITextProvider
{
    public SpecialTextbox ()
    {
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I created a new C# Windows Forms (.NET Framework) project, added a class as above, (added `using System.Windows.Forms;` namespace directive for `TextBox`, and created a dummy `ITextProvider` interface).  I went to Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > Toolbox > Automatically Populate Toolbox and set it to **true**.  I compiled the project with no errors (this is necessary) and finally opened up a designer for my `Form1` and showed the toolbox and the `SpecialTextbox` control appeared in the toolbox.   What did you do differently?

Comment: I am using an existing sample project from ReactiveUI, that's the only difference.  I'll try making one from scratch and see if that works.

Comment: Also, your title says that it's **not compiling**.  If it doesn't build successfully it won't be added to the toolbox.  But you said "after I build the solution".  So did the build succeed or not?  The title is conflicting with my understanding of what you tried.

Comment: So it won't build if I try to manually add the control to the form, if I comment out that code, it compiles.  I had hoped this would then show the control in the toolbox but it did not.  After the compile I commented the code back in, errors returned.

Comment: Out of curiosity...try declaring as `class SpecialTextbox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, ITextProvider`  (Fully qualified class name of `TextBox` - in case you have a doppleganger class hiding somewhere) Also, please be careful with case.  I see a lower case `b`.  But you've written both ways (upper & lower case) in your question.

Comment: Ok, so after creating a brand new project and just re-creating all the required bits (and adding the required nuget packages) I still don't see my control in the toolbox, but at least now the compiler seems happy to compile everything.  This is progress, let me try the full name idea in the old project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207697/discussion-between-bitfiddler-and-wyck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `SpecialTextbox` control is not a legit `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` (if you accidentally have a `MyApp.TextBox` or some other imposter class that you accidentally are using by not using a fully qualified name for the TextBox, and one that does not inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`) then it would explain both your errors:

1. That classes that aren't Controls won't appear in the Toolbox. (Because it's not a Control)
2. That it cannot be converted to System.Windows.Forms.Control (Because it's not a Control)

You have inherited from just `TextBox` and you likely have a `using` directive that specifies some other namespace's `TextBox` that isn't `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

Comment: Ok, so the tip to add the fully qualified name surfaced the issue.  When I create the class I typed out TextBox and then just hit control+enter to auto-add the using statement.  It defaulted to System.Windows.Controls.TextBox which to my eye looked right.  But apparently it should be System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.  Now everything works fine.  Thanks for you help Wyck!